# Ef Core 3.1 value convertor

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following code, that uses ef 3.1 core value conversion, I am getting the following error, any idea?

The entity type 'Address' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.

```
 public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
  }

  

  public class Address {
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
  }
```

```
  public class PersonsConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Person> {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> builder) {
      // This Converter will perform the conversion to and from Json to the desired type
      builder.Property(e => e.Addresses).HasConversion(
          v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }),
          v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Address>>(v, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the registering of the value conversions in the EntityTypeConfiguration does not work. Once I registered it in the DbContext OnModelCreating method - it started working.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
  modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType()));
  modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
   .Property(p => p.Address)
   .HasConversion(new JsonValueConverter<Address>());
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your address class needs a key. Try adding:

```
 [Key]
  public int AddressKey { get; set; }
```

To your address class.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want a table called Address created, just a column that stores teh JSON string in a field called Address in the person table. I know this could be done via a backing field, but looking for an option through value conversion.

Comment: @NairoozNIlafdeen have you solved your problem? I have the same issue and I don't realize how I will fix it. Thanks.